Как найти запись в ModngoDb используя часть ObjectId
Использовал много способов. Пытался через regex. Делал agrigate для создания новой строки внутри записей для последующего поиска. Пытался создавать регулярные выражения для имитации ObjectId. Ничего не помогает. Поиск по остальным параметрам работает хорошо.


if (searchQuery && searchQuery !== '') {
        
            const searchRegex = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i');
            query.$and.push({
                $or: [
                    { '_id': { $regex: searchRegex } },
                    {'id': { $regex: searchRegex }},
                    { 'deliveryDate': { $regex: searchRegex } },
                    { 'userAcc.name': { $regex: searchRegex } },
                    { 'userAcc.tradeName': { $regex: searchRegex } },
                    { 'idTucomida': { $regex: searchRegex } },
                    { 'description': { $regex: searchRegex } }
                ]
            });
        }



`

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/find-a-partial-object-id-in-mongosh/134005/2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72551342/4496422 https://stackoverflow.com/a/25689971/4496422 https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+search+by+part+of+objectid

Предложу такой вариант... {$where: function(){return /469/.test(this._id.toString())}}.

В итоге создаю новые записи с новым св-вом для поиска)
